# Using threading.local() in a kubernetes container

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a middleware in my app that sets the currently logged in user. On my local machine, get_current_user() works fine, but it seems to return None when the app is run in a kubernetes container. What am I missing?:

```
USER_ATTR_NAME = getattr(settings, "LOCAL_USER_ATTR_NAME", "_current_user")

_thread_locals = local()


def _do_set_current_user(user_fun):
    setattr(_thread_locals, USER_ATTR_NAME, user_fun.__get__(user_fun, local))


def _set_current_user(user=None):
    """
    Sets current user in local thread.
    Can be used as a hook e.g. for shell jobs (when request object is not
    available).
    """
    _do_set_current_user(lambda self: user)


class SelfServeCurrentUserMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # request.user closure; asserts laziness;
        # memorization is implemented in
        # request.user (non-data descriptor)
        _do_set_current_user(lambda self: getattr(request, "user", None))
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response


def get_current_user():
    current_user = getattr(_thread_locals, USER_ATTR_NAME, None)
    if callable(current_user):
        return current_user()
    return current_user


def get_current_authenticated_user():
    current_user = get_current_user()
    if isinstance(current_user, AnonymousUser):
        return None
    return current_user
```

Comment: Any reason you are using a thread local instead of the usual way to attach the user to the request? Thread locals can behave differently on different WSGI implementation.

Answer (score 0):

all what you do shows me - you don't really understand, how Django works.

What i mean:
You need User model, somewhere, probably it is form. You don't understand, how to get a user there, and you try to use locals. You made a import of functions get_current_user, get_current_authenticated_user. Now you can achieve a User. This is wrong for Django, but you can do it.

i have a small trick for you in this case:

```
from django.utils.translation.trans_real import _active as _thread_locals

# _thread_locals = local() you don't need it.

... # other staff
```

this is what you want. See the commentary about _active in django code